# Calling a method after a delay in a loop?

Tags: java, android

I found this answer:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    //Do something after 100ms
  }
}, 100);
```

but when I put that in a loop it activates instantaneously. If I use sleep() it will prevent the code inside from executing, so I can't figure out how I can do this.

Comment: What you use depends on what you're trying to do. Do you want to update the interface at an interval ? Do you want to run a long running operation without blocking the interface ?

Comment: yes i dont want to block the interface

Comment: You can use an [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several approaches how can you do this.

For instance,

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
try {
    Thread.sleep(100L);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
}
    //your background code.
      }
    }).start();
```